# How can I get Notepad++ to properly format, “pretty print” unformatted JSON data

Tags: notepad++

Apologies for the lacking terminology and such.

I would like to change a line like this one endless line:

```
{"GameDataObjects":[{"$type":"Game.GameData.AttributeGameData, Assembly-CSharp","DebugName":"Constitution","ID":"72712dca-8f95-42ef-bca1-be2e99f69de3","Components":[{"$type":"Game.GameData.AttributeComponent, Assembly-CSharp","Type" ... ...
```

To get it to look like this:

```
{
  "GameDataObjects": [
    {
      "$type": "Game.GameData.GlobalGameSettingsGameData, Assembly-CSharp",
      "DebugName": "GlobalGameSettings",
      "ID": "eddfc852-ccb9-4884-b901-e77e8ca31b48",
      "Components": [
        {
          "$type": "Game.GameData.CharacterStatsSettingsComponent, Assembly-CSharp",
          "BasePlayerLevelCap": 20,
          "MaxCharacterLevel": 30,
          "AttributeAverage": 10,
          "MaxPerceptionDistance": 7,
          "MaxStealthRadius": 4,
          "DefaultWalkSpeed": 2,
          "DefaultRunSpeed": 4,
          "DefaultAnimalCompanionWalkSpeed": 2,
          "DefaultAnimalCompanionRunSpeed": 5.5,
          "CombatHealthRechargeRate": 1,
          "NormalHealthRechargeRate": 10,
          "HealthRechargeDelay": 3,
          "ModalRecoveryTime": 3,
          "HitMultiplier": 1,
```

Comment: Answered on [SO]. See [How to reformat JSON in Notepad++? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560464/how-to-reformat-json-in-notepad)

Comment: Please don’t [edit your question to replace formatted text with screenshots](https://superuser.com/revisions/1447624/5). Screenshots are very hard to read and text in a question is easier to read and understand as well.

Answer (score 30):

You need to install JSON Viewer plugin in NotePad++.
plugins > plugin Manager > JSON Viewer > Install.
After plugin install select text you want to format and click on plugins > JSON Viewer > Format JSON.

Checkout latest version of Notepad++ to get all updated and latest plugins.

Comment: Solution still valid for August-2022, Thanks!

Comment: For completeness, the preferred solution in SO is JSTool (also available from Plugin Manager).  Apparently does everything JSON Viewer can, and more.

Comment: If you don't have Plugins Admin then see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560464/how-to-reformat-json-in-notepad#77899046